# C Noob: Define size of a char array while copying contents of char* into it

Tags: c

I have a basic question in C.

I need to print the contents of a char pointer. The contents are binary and therefore I use hex format to see the contents.

Would detecting a null still work?

```
unsigned char *input = "������";
printf("input =");
int count = 0;
while(*input != '\0'){
    printf("%02x", *input);
            input++;
}
printf("\n");
```

Now what happens if I have to copy the pointer to a char array?
How can I assign the size of the char array? I understand sizeof returns only the size of datatype that char points to. But is there any way?

```
unsigned char copyInput[size??];
strcpy(copyInput, input);
for (i=0, i <size?, i++)
{
printf("copyInput[%d]= %02x", i, copyInput[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1) To the extent that C has strings at all, they are defined as "an arbitrary contiguous sequence of nonzero bytes, terminated with a zero byte".  Therefore, if your binary data is guaranteed never to *contain* bytes whose value is zero, you can safely treat it as a C string (use the `str*` functions with it, etc).  But if your binary data might have zero bytes somewhere in the middle, you need to track the length separately and operate on it with the `mem*` functions instead.

2) You use `strlen` to find the length of the string (without the terminating zero byte).  However, in standard C89 you can't use the result of `strlen` to set the size of a `char[]` variable, because the size has to be known at compile time.  If you're using C99 or GNU extensions, you *can* define the size of an array at runtime:

```
size_t n = strlen(s1);
char s2[n+1];
memcpy(s2, s1, n);
```

The `n+1` is necessary, or you won't have space for the terminating NUL.  If you can't use C99 nor GNU extensions, your only option is to allocate space on the heap:

```
size_t n = strlen(s1);
char *s2 = malloc(n+1);
memcpy(s2, s1, n);
```

or, with a common library extension, just

```
char *s2 = strdup(s1);
```

Either way, don't forget to `free(s2)` later.  By the way, this is a case where it would have been safe to use `strcpy`, because you know by construction that the destination buffer is big enough.  I used `memcpy` because it may be slightly more efficient and it means human readers won't see "strcpy" and start worrying.

Comment: Do you say I could still use null termination to detect end of a binary string as I have used? Is size_t the right way to assign lengths? I get a "conflicting type" warning when I tried your code :(

Comment: You can still use null termination to detect the end of a binary string *as long as the binary data is guaranteed to contain no zero bytes*.  If any byte of the actual data might be all-bits-zero, you need to store the length separately.  I'll clarify my part 1.  Re size_t, yes, that is *supposed* to be the correct type.  I'd need to see the exact error message and know which line of code it didn't like, to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: size_t ncount = strlen(text);
   char s2[ncount+1];
   memcpy(s2, text, ncount);
   printf("s2 =");
   for(i = 0; i < ncount; i++){
    printf("%x", s2[i]);
   }
Returns a warning that "pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strlen' differ in signedness"
Also, s2 has some ffffextra characters :(

Comment: Ah, that has nothing to do with `size_t`; the pointer you passed to `strlen` has type `unsigned char *` rather than `char *`.  If this only comes up in a few places, silence the warning with a cast; if you have this problem in many places, I would add an inline wrapper function `ustrlen(unsigned char *)` that does the cast, so you will still get told when you pass completely the wrong type.  I don't know what's with the extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a bunch of `char`s terminated with a 0, just use `strlen()` since that is C's definition of a string. It doesn't matter than some (or most) of the characters might be unprintable, as long as 0 is the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems if any of the input bytes are 0. In this case the loop will stop at that character. Otherwise, you can treat it as a string.

Treating it as a string, you can use `strlen()` to get the input's size and then dynamically allocate memory to your copy. The copy can be made with `strcpy` as you did, but it is safer to use `strncpy`.

```
char *input = "input binary array";
int count = strlen(input)+1; // plus '\0'
char *copy = (char *) malloc(count*sizeof(char));
strncpy(copy, input, count+1);
```

Comment: but I want to copy it to a char array and print it. How would that be?

Comment: The `copy` is a dynamic allocated char array. You can print the values the same way you did with `copyInput` in your explanation.